# Add dynamically buttons to layout in android

Tags: android

I was wondering how can I add dynamically buttons to layout from code. I don;t know how many buttons I will should add. This number will be random. I want to add them in this way:
[image]

Any ideas how can I do that dynamically in this way?

Comment: so the number of the button will be determinde from random number?

Comment: what about your parent layout.. xml? or dynamic?

Comment: @NAYOSO, yes, this will be random value. One time number of buttons will be 4 other time can be 10 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way to add button:

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("Button");

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.addView(myButton, lp);

Button myButton1 = new Button(this);
myButton1.setText("Button1");

ll.addView(myButton1, lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

create one linearlayout with horizontal orientation and add two buttons on that.. when you have more than two buttons then add another linearlayout with horizontal for that buttons..